# How can I write a Generator with an ImageParam that has a type specified as a GeneratorParam?

Tags: c++, halide

I would like to implement an image pipeline for various image data types. I am defining a `Generator` class containing the `build()` method describing the pipeline, a `GeneratorParam<type>` to specify the data type parameter and an `ImageParam` member to specify the input image. If I specify the type of the `ImageParam` to be the `GeneratorParam<Type>` that I have defined above, then no matter what type I specify when I execute the generator, the type of the input image is always the default type. If I copy the declaration of the `ImageParam` inside the body of the `build()` method, then it seems to be working fine. Is this the correct way to define a pipeline with an input image that can have different types?

Here is the class as I originally wrote it:

```cpp
#include "Halide.h"

using namespace Halide;

class myGenerator : public Generator<myGenerator>
{
public:
    // Image data type as a parameter of the generator; default: float
    GeneratorParam<Type> datatype{"datatype", Float(32)};

    // Input image to the pipeline
    ImageParam input{datatype, 3, "input"}; // datatype=Float(32) always

    // Pipeline
    Func build()
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

If I compile the generator and run it to generate a pipeline for a `datatype` different from the default:

```bash
$ ./myGenerator -f pipeline_uint8 -o . datatype=uint8
```

Then everything seems fine, but the pipeline crashes at runtime because the buffer that I pass to it is uint8, but it was expecting an image of type float (the default I have specified in the generator class):

```bash
Error: Input buffer input has type float32 but elem_size of the buffer passed in is 1 instead of 4
```

I have fixed the issue by copying the declaration of the `ImageParam` inside the `build()` block, but that seems a little bit dirty to me. Is there a better way? Here is the class now:

```cpp
#include "Halide.h"

using namespace Halide;

class myGenerator : public Generator<myGenerator>
{
public:
    // Image data type as a parameter of the generator; default: float
    GeneratorParam<Type> datatype{"datatype", Float(32)};

    // Input image to the pipeline
    ImageParam input{datatype, 3, "input"};

    // Pipeline
    Func build()
    {
        // Copy declaration. This time, it picks up datatype
        // as being the type inputted when executing the
        // generator instead of using the default.
        ImageParam input{datatype, 3, "input"};

        // ...
    }
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed dirty. The current best known solution is reinitializing input with the correct type at the top of build, rather than shadowing it with another ImageParam with the same name:

```
Func build() 
{
    input = ImageParam{datatype, 3, "input"};
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: @Andrew: How would you solve this using the new generators with a `Input<Buffer<...>>`?